# Need some ideas on creative DOM grabbing for a confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery

What this little script does is it creates a context menu (right click) that has two options, delete and edit. Ideally it would just ask to confirm to delete, because it is not the end of the world if you accidentally get taken to the modify screen. But in either case, I would like to create some kind of unique message to each situation to display to the user.

```
$("#myDiv").contextMenu({

  menu: 'myMenu'

},

  function(action, el, pos) {    
  var yesno = confirm(    
  'Are you sure?'
   //you would like to delete? 
   //you would like to edit

);
  if (yesno == true) { 
    window.location(action);
  }

});
```

---

```
<div id="myDiv">

   Right click for options.

</div>

<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">

  <li class="edit">   <a href="some/edit/page">   Edit   </a></li>
  <li class="delete"> <a href="some/delete/page"> Delete </a></li>

</ul>
```

---

I am not sure of what the accepted methodology would be in this case to grab some information about the actions, because the last thing I want is to write some super convoluted code when there is an easier way to do it.

This code seems moderately flexible, so I can add some more divs, or something like that. However, I would like to avoid a tag soup situation.

Comment: Would be nice if you could more clearly define a question here.

Comment: The question is clearly defined enough. Its meant to be amorphous to just get ideas not code.

Comment: Maybe clear to you, but judging from the lack of responses it may not be clear to others.

Comment: I would like to create some kind of unique confirmation message to each situation to display to the user based on if they are deleting or editing.

Comment: If it's just stylish boxes you're looking for I would google some variations of "jQuery" and "modal lightbox". Theres a ton of stuff available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using jQuery Alert plugin

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/